# Why doesn't the very first bitcoin release work anymore?

Tags: bitcoin-core, history

I tried running the very first bitcoin client released by Satoshi in 2009, `Bitcoin v0.1.0` on Windows 10. Of course I knew it wouldn't work or do anything since it's extremely outdated, but I wanted to try it anyway out of curiosity.

It runs but doesn't make any connections and can't download the blockchain. Is there a technical reason for this?

Comment: Did you give it a few nodes to connect to? The mechanism that it uses to find initial nodes won't work anymore because it's long since been replaced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74323/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/90811/5406